# QGIS: Problems due to vectoral layers in QGIS3.10

Tags: shapefile, qgis

I have just set up the QGIS3.10, and now I can not see the vectorial layers. In fact the program says that they have no objects and I did not have this problem with the previous versions of the QGIS.

I will show you the problem in an image:

[image: There is no information of the shape file]

Anyone knows why this situation it is happening ?

thank you very much,

Marta

Comment: What kind of layer?  What data was used to create the layer?

Comment: A point layer, but it is very strange because in other computers the layer works perfectly.

Comment: My QGIS projects are shape files (.shp).  My base maps and any layers I've added live in the same folder. When I right click the name of the layer and then select Properties, then select Information, I see the Path and Storage.  The Storage is, "ESRI Shapefile".    FYI,  every shape files (.shp) requires two other files in the same folder with these extensions ( .shx & .dbf ) .  Try opening a new OSM base map, and then add a new vector layer (point or line or polygon) , save , then examine the folder where these files are saved.